# Power query formula that import Excel files as separeted tables

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery

I have this formula to import using the power query advanced editor in Excel, but this combine all the excel files in to one single table I would to generate a sheet with a table for each excel document that is in the folder, is that possible and in case the answers is yes could someone help me complement my code?

This is my example of data: File with [data city 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-NEwPzlfSVcTRFpkhkUOPnomdC9Ps0-9p_6_zPXNDwM/edit?usp=sharing) So here is an example with the data from two cities File with [data city 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pmp062c6Apijda1YyqdPxrb-MY7k_ra3Tj5PB0Mmnw4/edit?usp=sharing), when I tried to use the formula the power query don't import the data to excel.

The example will be having both files in a folder, and with the formula import this two a two different tables in two different sheets

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

Comment: There is no such thing as splitting a query into different output sheets. If you want every one of these files output to a different sheet, you need to make them separate queries. If your issue is that the number of files in that directory may change, that is a different proposition.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to make a main query, then reference it in other queries that pare that information down and then output it to separate sheets, but the question would be, "Why?"

Comment: To give you more context my code was made to for this scenario:  So basically I have a dashboard that I have to update with new data so what do I need is and option to just replace the original excel file that contains the data with another one but with diffent data and without affecting the graphs just updating the data with the new one

Comment: There is a way to do this with one file? because I tried before and it didn't work with the function data get data from Excel then I try to copy paste a excel file with the same name and same columns with the same names but I got an error

Comment: I can't help you without more information. Your sample data doesn't really do much to explain it, or I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you have a file that is the basis for a query, and you swap out that file with another one that has the exact same structure, the query should not break.

What I thought you are doing is [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-a-folder-with-multiple-files-power-query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4). By design it produces one query.

Comment: If you want to create two different queries off the bat, you will need to import the files separately. BTW, it appears I was wrong, you [CAN split a query](https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/split-a-query-into-two-parts-in-power-query/).